# Tkinter grid in Gender option

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

How we set the grid for gender so that they will be close to 2 columns only.
I want gender(label), male and female(options) are packed into 2 columns.
Here is my code...

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title('Registration Form')

head = Frame(root)
entry = Frame(root)

head.pack()
entry.pack()

var = StringVar()

heading = Label(head,text='Registration Form',font='Helvetica 25 bold',pady=10).pack()

name_label = Label(entry,text='Name  ',font='Helvetica 10 bold',pady=5)
name_entry = Entry(entry,width=30, font='Helvetica 10')

email_label = Label(entry,text='Email  ',font='Helvetica 10 bold',pady=5)
email_entry = Entry(entry,width=30, font='Helvetica 10')

mob_label = Label(entry,text='Mobile  ',font='Helvetica 10 bold',pady=5)
mob_entry = Entry(entry,width=30, font='Helvetica 10')

gender_label = Label(entry,text='Gender  ',font='Helvetica 10 bold',pady=5)
male = Radiobutton(entry,text='Male',variable=var,value='male')
female = Radiobutton(entry,text='Female',variable=var,value='female')

name_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
name_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
email_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
email_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
mob_label.grid(row=3, column=1)
mob_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)
gender_label.grid(row=4, column=1)
male.grid(row=4,column=2, sticky="nsew")
female.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: put `male` or `famale` in next column. Use `columnspan=2` for widgets above genders.

Comment: but i want to put both in same row.

Comment: got it. Thank you...

Comment: An alternative is creating a frame at 4,2 then creating two radiobuttons in that one. With that you avoid adding columnspan to all `column=2` items.

Answer (score 1):

Put `male` or `female` in next column and use `columnspan=2` for `Entry`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

name_label = Label(root, text='Name')
name_entry = Entry(root)

gender_label = Label(root, text='Gender')
male = Radiobutton(root, text='Male')
female = Radiobutton(root, text='Female')

name_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
name_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)

gender_label.grid(row=4, column=1)
male.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="nsew")
female.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

See on effbot.org: [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)